# Troubleshooting two-step nested model signup process

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, registration, nested-forms

I want to initiate a sign-up process on my homepage. In the end, the process ideally would follow the following logic:

```
user = User.new
user.email = ""
user.password = ""
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.info = ""
user.profile.save
user.save
```

I'll be using nested model forms, of course. But is there a way to spread this into two parts? In part 1 the `User` would enter mainly `user` information, as well as a bit of `profile` information, and part 2 would contain solely 'profile' information. Then when all is said and done the user gets redirected to their user profile.

If this is possible, what is the general thinking on this type of process? Second, I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out how to achieve it. I have the nested model forms all set up but there must be something messed up in my routes.rb file/Controllers that is denying me the experience.

**Here's my routes.rb file.**

```
get "profiles/show"
get "/profiles/:id" => "profiles#show", :as => "profile"
post "/signup" => "profiles#create", :as => "signup"
get "skip/signup", :to => "users#newskip"
match "skip/profiles/new", :to => "profiles#newskip"
root :to => "users#new"
```

**And here are my UsersController and ProfilesController respectively:**

```
*class UsersController < ApplicationController*
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to signup_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

*class ProfilesController < ApplicationController*
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user.profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile), :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Can anyone help show me the light? I know Devise is a solution but I'm trying to learn without that. At least at first. This [previous question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581172/linking-two-models-in-a-multi-model-form) looks like a potential starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed this by having `user` and `profile` create on the homepage, Profiles#edit as the second step, with a redirect_to profile.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) is a Railscast about multistep forms. I think it should put you on track for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Actually, it looks like this SO post is just about what I'm looking for (minus Devise): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825135/devise-sign-up-page-as-welcome-landing-page-then-to-user-profile. I want the user to sign-up on the homepage, then immediately be taken to their profile.